# How to Implement SSJS ContinueRequest?

Tags: javascript, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ssjs

How do I implement ContinueRequest on a script like below to bypass the 2500 limit?

```
    <script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
try {

var DEkey = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("DEkey");
var myDE = DataExtension.Init(DEkey);
 
var data = myDE.Rows.Retrieve();  
  
Write(data.length);

  } catch (error) {
    Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ssjs](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssjs) tags.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to retrieve more than 2500 records from a Data Extension with WSProxy https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-retrieve-more-than-2500-records-from-a-data-extension-with-server-side-javascript/